# php regex to find words in string starting with # and not have any more repeated #

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, arabic, hashtag

I'm looking for a  regex to find words in string starting with # and not have any more repeated #

Given:

```
Hi I'm #hany #هانى my Friend #john#john is ##here . good bye#all .
```

I want the final result as this:

```
Hi I'm <a>#hany</a> <a>#هانى</a> my Friend #john#john is ##here . good bye#all .
```

I'm using this:

```
echo preg_replace('/(?!\b)#(\\S+)/','<a>$0</a>',$string);
```

I want only words starting with `#` and not have any more hashes like twitter hash-tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
echo preg_replace('/(?<=\s)(#[^#\s]+)(?=\s)/', '<a>$0</a>' ,$string);
```

Output:

```
Hi I'm <a>#hany</a> <a>#هانى</a> my Friend #john#john is ##here . good bye#all .
```

Comment: it works fine ,but i want to echo <a>$1</a> 
output like: 
    Hi I'm <a>hany</a> <a>هانى</a> my Friend #john#john is ##here . good bye#all .

and another one to scape the non english words 
output like:
    Hi I'm <a>hany</a> #هانى my Friend #john#john is ##here . good bye#all .

Comment: i modified it to:  

echo preg_replace('/(?<=\s)#([^#\s]+)(?=\s)/', '<a>$0</a>' ,$string);

and to scape non-english words:

echo preg_replace('/(?<=\s)@([^@\W]+)(?=\s)/', '<a>$0</a>' ,$string);


thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
echo preg_replace('~(?<=\s|^)#[^\s#]++~um', '<a>$0</a>', $string);
```

Explanations:

```
~             # pattern delimiter (instead of /, but it's the same)
(?<=          # open a lookbehind (means "preceded by")
    \s | ^    # a white character (space, tab, newline...) or the begining of the line
)             # close the lookbehind
#             # literal #
[^\s#]++      # all that is not a # or a white character, one or more times (possessive)
~             # delimiter
um            # u for unicode string, m for multiline mode
```